# Reference for Dyck languages being $\mathsf{TC}_0$-complete

Tags: reference-request, fl.formal-languages, circuit-complexity, ho.history-overview, context-free

Dyck languages $\mathsf{Dyck}(k)$ is defined by the following grammar
$$
S \rightarrow SS \,|\, (_1 S )_1 \,|\, \ldots \,|\, (_k S )_k \,|\, \epsilon
$$
over the set of symbols $\{(_1,\ldots,(_k,)_1,\ldots,)_k\}$.  Intuitively Dyck languages are the languages of balanced parentheses of $k$ different kind.  For example, $(\,[\,]\,)\,(\,)$ is in $\mathsf{Dyck}(2)$ but $(\,[\,)\,]$ is not.

In the paper

> [Dynamic Algorithms for the Dyck Languages](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.29.5560&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Frandsen, Husfeldt, Miltersen, Rauhe, and Skyum, 1995,

it is claimed that the following result is folklore:

> $\mathsf{Dyck}(k)$ is $\mathsf{TC}_0$-complete under $\mathsf{AC}_0$ reductions.

Is there any reference known for the above claim?  In particular, I'm looking for any results that shows at least one of the following:

- $\mathsf{Dyck}(k)$ is in $\mathsf{TC}_0$ for arbitrary $k$.
- $\mathsf{Dyck}(k)$ is $\mathsf{TC}_0$-hard for arbitrary $k$.

---

The closest paper I can find is

> [Bi-Lipschitz Bijection between the Boolean Cube
>   and the Hamming Ball](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.2017), by Benjamini, Cohen, and Shinkar, 2013

which redirects me to the paper [Log space recognition and translation of parenthesis languages](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.19.7200&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Lynch who proved that $\mathsf{Dyck}(1)$ (that is, normal balanced parentheses) is in $\mathsf{TC_0}$.

Any related papers are welcomed as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See "On the relative complexity of some languages in $\mathsf{NC}^1$ by [Barrington,Corbett](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190%2889%2990052-5)

Answer (score 7):

Here is an $AC_0$ reduction from $\rm Majority$ to $Dyck(1)$.
(This implies that $\rm Majority$ is $AC_0$ reducible to $Dyck(k)$ for all $k \geq 1$.)
In order to do it, we construct a poly-size
constant depth circuit whose gates are $AND$, $OR$, $NOT$ and $Dyck(1)$.

---

- Given an instance $x \in \{0,1\}^n$ of $\rm Majority$ do
- Compute $y \in \{0,1\}^{2n}$ by replacing each $0$ with $(($ and each $1$ with $()$.
- Now for each $i = 1,\dots, n/2$ let $z_i$ be the string obtained by concatenating $y$ with $2i$-many closing parentheses, i.e. $z_i = y \circ )^{2i}$.
- If $z_i \in Dyck(1)$ for some $i = 1,\dots, n/2$ then ACCEPT.
  Otherwise, REJECT.

---

This can be clearly done with a constant depth circuit. (Computing $z_i$ can be done in depth 1, and computing the last step is done using an $OR$ gate.)

It is also easy to see that this circuit indeed computes $\rm Majority$ because $z_i \in Dyck(1)$ if and only if ${\rm weight}(x) = n - i$.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know any paper that contains the result above?  (It is ok if the paper is not the original/earliest one, I am trying to trace back the history.)

Comment: Hmmm... for some reason I assumed that a similar reduction appeared in that paper of Lynch... I don't know any other reference for this.